# Access sub elements inside form using ajaxform

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

A page might contain multiple form with similar structure. I use ajaxform to submit the form data. And while submitting and after response, i populate the results in the div, located within the same form.

```
$('#a').ajaxForm({
          beforeSubmit:function(){
            $('#a').find('.overlay').removeClass('hide');
          },
          success:function(data){
            result = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#a').find('.alert_container').html(result.response);
            $('#a').find('.overlay').addClass('hide');
          },
});
```

Above code works find, but the problem remains, i have to make an individual copy for each forms.

How do you access the child divs or elements using ajaxform on each form using the similar following code?

```
$('form').ajaxForm({
          beforeSubmit:function(){
            $(this).find('.overlay').removeClass('hide');
          },
          success:function(data){
            result = JSON.parse(data);
            $(this).find('.alert_container').html(result.response);
            $(this).find('.overlay').addClass('hide');
          },
});
```

$(this) doesn't seem to work within this case.